# ObjectDataSource in 3-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, objectdatasource, 3-tier

For a long time I've been using ObjectDataSource in c# and vb.net for binding data to asp controls (dropdownlist, gridview, listbox, etc.), but as I've been reading, when it comes to a 3-tier architecture application, if I have my 3 tier/layers (projects), eg.

```
Data
Business
Presentation
```

Presentation should only know about Business, and Business should only know about Data. But when using an ObjectDataSource it's necessary to make the Data tier visible to the Presentation tier(by reference)

My question goes to,

- Does this affect performance?
- Does it go against 3-tier architecture principles?
- Is it better to perform a manual binding, even if it consumes coding time?
- What are the risks of using ObjectDataSource objects when it comes to big apps/projects?

Comment: You are essentially not exposing your data objects directly. Your object data source will only be your business layer component

Comment: @qamar Even if I use .xsd objects (TableAdapter, DataTable) from my Data tier?

Comment: You are exposing TA, DT to the business layer, then you are going to use those business layer components as object data source from your aspx.

Comment: @qamar My question comes when using ODS in an ASPX page, I mean, not using an object Data Source by coding it into my Business Layer but calling them directly from Presentation, in visual designer.

Comment: I understand now.....I am not really comfortable in embedding database related mark up or source in the aspx. But MS allows them with no good reason. I think there is no definitive answer to this question but in my opinion its bad practice. I think you should take note of asp.net model binding feature to strongly type your aspx pages. So that your pages are aware of your model changes